# hook for switch user link click

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7

I have the switch user list for admin login I want to do a action in user login. I want to do the same in switch user link click .`hook_user_login(&$edit,$account)` is not working for switch user.Is there hook for switch user link's click. hook `hook_user_login(&$edit,$account)` is working fine for my own account druring login instead of switch user.

How to do user_login hook for switch user for development in drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the switch user from devel module? If you use that one, the hook_user_login will still being called when switching user. You can check the devel_switch_user function in devel module.

Comment: ya using switch user from devel module.

Comment: but the parameter $account doesn't return user details

Comment: I did a test with the code below and the user object details is assigned to the $account

    function custom_testing_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
        var_dump($account);exit;
        watchdog('testing', 'test login', array(), WATCHDOG_INFO);
    }

 If you put your code here maybe I can help to troubleshoot it

Answer (score 0):

To make login programmatically use the below code:

```
$empty = $form_state = array();
$form_state['uid'] = $uid; // your user id
user_login_submit($empty, $form_state);
```

or use the module [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade). Which allows site administrators (or anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no password required). That person can switch back to their own user account at any time.